# What is the name for amplitude variation over time with angle measurement called?

Tags: real-time, amplitude-modulation

I am trying to create a method in my real-time algorithm to measure the variation in time based on a simple technique to avoid a huge overhead in the processing on the hardware.

The first method I am defining is measuring the angle shift between features in the time series as you see in the following image. Is there a name for this technique? because it is not phase measurement. Perhaps, amplitude variation?
[image]

Comment: Hard to say but if it's amplitude drift over time, it could be "slope" perhaps? This really depends on the context

Comment: If I were to give it a name I would call it amplitude drift or variation but I have never seen such measure using the angle but comparing trends keeping huge amount of data. I don't know, I'm just curious ifthis technique already exists.